# How to send @Input to multiple components?

Tags: angular, html, input, routes

I want to send an @Input() to two different components : one is a list-item, the other is a item-detail. They should use more or less the same properties.

I tried to use different Service to send the same input, with and without Observable and Subscribe, but I always get the same error message when I try to show my item-detail component : *"Cannot read property "property" of undefined"*. The list-item is working fine.

Here's my code :

List HTML :

```
<div class="container list-group">
  <a *ngFor="let actu of actus" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" [routerLink]="['/article', actu.id]">
    <app-item-actus [actu]="actu"></app-item-actus>
  </a>
  <div *ngFor="let actu of actus" class="hide">
    <app-actu-detail [article]="actu" class="hide"></app-actu-detail>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Here I try a hidden *ngFor to send my items to the detail (class="hide" is a display: none).

List TS :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ActuService } from 'src/app/services/actu.service';
import { Actu } from '../../../modeles/actu';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-liste-actus',
  templateUrl: './liste-actus.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./liste-actus.component.css']
})

export class ListeActusComponent implements OnInit {

  actus: Actu[];

  constructor(private actuService: ActuService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.actuService.getActusList().subscribe(data => { this.actus = data; });
  }
}
```

I didn't used Observable to check if the result is the same or not but nothing seems to change.

Item-detail HTML

```
<div>
  <h2>{{article.titre}}</h2>
  <br>
  <blockquote *ngIf="article.exergue"><i>{{article.exergue}}</i> 
  </blockquote>
  <br>
  <figure>
    <img *ngIf="article.image" src="{{article.image}}" alt="image article">
    <figcaption>{{article.legendeImage}}</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <br>
  <p *ngIf="article.paragraphe1">{{article.paragraphe1}}</p>
  <br>
  <h4 *ngIf="article.intertitre1">{{article.intertitre1}}</h4>
  <br>
  <p *ngIf="article.paragraphe2">{{article.paragraphe2}}</p>
  <br>
  <h4 *ngIf="article.intertitre2">{{article.intertitre2}}</h4>
  <br>
  <p *ngIf="article.paragraphe3">{{article.paragraphe3}}</p>
  <br>
</div>
```

Here is my Item-detail HTML that is more or less the same as my List-item with more properties to show.

Item-detail TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actu-detail',
  templateUrl: './actu-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./actu-detail.component.css']
})
export class ActuDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() article: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I use a spring generated project + mysql as back and DB and I new to the coding world so I might have done some big mistake somewhere but I can't figure out where.

Thanks in advance for your help with my problem.

Comment: Just asking sidely, why dont you just merge both `*ngFor` in a simple one since they share the same loop?

Comment: share you app-item-actus component cde

Comment: Code is more or less the same as actu-detail.

I change my code so both components are now in ngFor, same result but better look, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Does someone got a solution for this problem ? Isn't a problem with routerLink too ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add a *ngIf to ensure your data are defined before the loop :

```
<div class="container list-group" *ngIf="actus">
...
</div>
```

If you want to avoid the white screen while data is being fetched, you have to use resolvers https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: Added the *ngIf on my list component, still working and should be useful for my next project :). It doesn't make a change here as I did'nt have white screen problem.  I took a look to Resolve but it seems a little bit to difficult for my actual knowledge in Angular :(

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is happening because when you are mounting the component, the property you are passing to the component is undefined, so you can not access to a property of undefined. You can solve this issue adding a default value to the input in your component:

in `app-item-actus`:

```
@Input() actu: any = {};
```

Also in `app-actu-detail` you are sending the a prop called `[article]`:
so you should receive it like:

```
@Input() article: any = {};
```

Comment: Tried your change, I'm not getting the error anymore but I still got a blank page. The list didnt move either, which is fine.